# Generate Ruby classes from XML Schema Definition (XSD)

Tags: ruby, xml, xsd

What is the preferred way to build a Ruby API for writing XML files based on an existing XSD file?

I know there is xsd2ruby from soap4r, but the generated classes are not very useful, IMHO:

- The generated initializer has lots of parameters, one for each attribute. I would like to have a Hash param instead
- For restrictions (length, enumeration, patterns, ...) no code is generated

What do you use today? Having generated Ruby classes for a complex XSD file would be very helpful.

Comment: Try [`Nokogiri`](http://nokogiri.org/). If you provide one sample input and expected output,then I can try here...

Comment: Nokogiri can generate Ruby classes (.rb files) from an .xsd file? I can't find anything about this in the Nokogiri docs...

Comment: Realizing that this question is already some old, I wonder if anyone has found a way of doing it. Any clue or help will be appreciated.